# Parameterizing the argument to a function in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to procedurally change the cell number arguments passed to the TRANSPOSE function as shown in the below code block.

Alternatively, I would be happy if I could evaluate the strings that I have generated below to show my end goal using a method akin to excel's EVALUATE function.

Thus looking for advice on how to execute a string as a formula, or on how to parameterize the cell number arguments passed to TRANSPOSE as the below snip shows.

formulas to generate:

```
=TRANSPOSE('Running Log'!B4:B10)
=TRANSPOSE('Running Log'!B11:B17)
=TRANSPOSE('Running Log'!B18:B24)
=TRANSPOSE('Running Log'!B25:B31)
=TRANSPOSE('Running Log'!B32:B38)
=TRANSPOSE('Running Log'!B39:B45)
=TRANSPOSE('Running Log'!B46:B52)
=TRANSPOSE('Running Log'!B53:B59)
=TRANSPOSE('Running Log'!B60:B66)
.
.
.
```

I tried the below custom function but was not successful

```
function gsEval(myCell) {
    myCell.setFormula(myCell.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Use `SEQUENCE()` function with `INDEX()`.

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged the question with 'google-sheets-formula' so I don't know if you actually need a script-based answer like the custom function you've tried or not, however the result of the block of TRANSPOSEs you've shown would also be generated by the following simple formula:

```
=wraprows('Running Log'!B4:B66,7)
```